# Selecting from a PDO object with fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason the following code always returns true, no matter what the parameter is and what is actually inside of the SQL row.  It also throws an error "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\Social Networking\INC\login.inc on line 7" but I do not see what is wrong:

```
<?php
function checkAccount($username, $password){
    include("INC/dbconnect.inc");/*"INC/dbconnect.inc" is <?php $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=socialnetwork","user","123"); ?>*/
    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id,password FROM users WHERE user_username = :username");
    $select->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
    $q_rows = $select->fetchAll();
    if($q_rows[0][0]/*the ID of the user, it should always be greater than 1, if not then the username does not exist*/ > 0 && $q_rows[0][0] != null){
        if($q_rows[0][1]/*the password of the user*/ == $password)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
    $pdo=null;
} ?>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? I have commented inside of the code the problems I am experiencing, and I have tried normal `$select->fetch()` instead of `$select->fetchAll()` to no avail.  I have read up on PDO before posting this (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).  Here is the rest of my file http://pastebin.com/YCkrRivs, thanks.

Comment: make sure you really understand the difference between `return "false";` and `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

If the database returns no rows, then there will be no entry `$q_rows[0]`. Hence, undefined offset 0 as you are trying to retrieve a row in array that doesn't exist. Your 'ID' not > 0 for non-existent user is not a correct summary.

Sample return looks like this (if you print_r()'d it)

User present:

```
$q_rows = Array (
  [0] => Array ( 
   [id] => 1,
   [password] => 'dno23n3io3'
  )
)
```

No user present:

```
$q_rows = Array (
)
```

You should do:

```
if(size($q_rows) > 0) {
   //Handle user present
} else {
   //Handle no user present
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and also tried the print_r() to find out what was wrong, but for some reason print_r() would not write anything to the page and now all the function does is return false (after fixing the "true" and "false" returns... derp!)

Comment: I did some debugging and I have found the problem. I thought that sha512 was always consistently kept 32 digits long, but that is not the case. Therefore all of the digits already in my table were not matching the longer encrypt from the password input. After fixing the hash, this worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `fetchAll`, just use `fetch`:

```
$q_row = $select->fetch();

if ($q_row) {
  // do your logic ...
}
```

And you are returning strings `"true"/"false"`, not the boolean, you should use `true/false` instead.

More simple, you could just do like below:

```
$q_row = $select->fetch();
return $q_row && $q_row[0] > 0 && $q_row[1] === $password;
```

Comment: Also a good answer as you shouldn't have multiple users with the same username so there is no value in 'fetchAll'. I'm not sure the collapsed return is particularly transparent, but it's neat..

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately it does not work, even with adding `count($q_row) > 0` and taking out `$q_row[0] > 0` as [Philip Whitehouse](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1052931/philip-whitehouse) said in his previous answer.  Now all the function does is return false (after fixing the "true" and "false" returns... derp!)

Comment: @Spectrewiz There could be some other problems in your code, do some debugging work.

Comment: xdazz and @Philip_Whitehouse I did some debugging and I think I may have found the problem.  I thought that sha512 was always consistently kept 32 digits long, but that is not the case.  Therefore all of the digits already in my table were not matching the longer encrypt from the password input.  I'll fix this and I will get back to you with the results :)